# Android Marshmallow 6.0, opening gallery via intent says No apps to perform the action

Tags: android, gallery, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-7

I am trying to open gallery on Nexus 7 with Android 6.0. It does not have in built gallery, but it does have the **Google Photos** app.

I am using the following code to open the gallery :

```
    Intent i = new intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

The above code works well in all the versions below 6.0. And Please note that I am already using RUN TIME PERMISSIONS for accessing gallery and have given the permission to access gallery / or externa storage.

Now when the code is executed, I get a transparent screen with heading "Select Picture" and in the middle a text **No Apps can perform this action.**

Now what do I do to pick or choose image and use in my app.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my code. I just want to start i.
Actually , I am using this code , so that only gallery opens and not any other option to pick image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using the following code to open the gallery

That code has nothing to do with a "gallery". That code is requesting to pick a piece of content from a particular collection of content. There may be zero, one, or several activities on the device that offer to support that `Intent` structure.

> The above code works well in all the versions below 6.0

Only on devices that happen to have one or more activities that satisfies that `Intent` structure.

> Now what do I do to pick or choose image and use in my app.

```
Intent i = new intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*");

// use PackageManager to see if there is anything that supports this
// Intent structure, or just blindly make the following call and handle
// the ActivityNotFoundException

startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

> I am using this code , so that only gallery opens and not any other option to pick image

There is nothing in your code that limits it to just a "gallery".

Answer (score 0):

Not allowed to comment because I don't have enough points. But here's just a suggestion, how about if you just passed the intent directly? Like this:

```
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code rather than what you have done

```
Intent i = new intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```